# jQuery script keeps redirecting me from a page I'm trying to edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-online

I was trying to make an application in SharePoint and wanted to make it so that if you click on a button, it redirects you to a page and when that page loads I wanted it to instantly redirect the user to another page. ( I couldn't get the button to just redirect to the page I wanted on click, so that's why I tried doing it this way. ) I did this using a jQuery / JavaScript script. I'm new to making scripts so I was just testing and I ended up making this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        Redirect();
});

    function Redirect(){
    $(document).load("url");
}
</script>
```

My problem is now that whenever that page loads, it just loads a blank page. But I can't get to the edit screen because it instantly redirects me to a blank page. I tried turning off JavaScript in Google Chrome but even though I was able to load the page without redirecting, I wasn't able to get to the edit page because it's in a jQuery AJAX drop down menu which obviously also doesn't work if JavaScript is turned off.

I would appreciate any help

EDIT: When I say edit screen I mean the place where I can edit the script. To do that I have to press a button on the page, but I can't do that since the page instantly redirects to a blank page.

Comment: have you tried the `onclick` event on your button so when the on click triggers it will load your page

Comment: I have, but I didn't manage to get it to work because I can't edit the html of the site, only through scripts, but yeah I don't think it's possible. But the problem I have now is trying to get to the edit screen of that page.

Comment: you can make it throw the javascript only if your button have a unique id or class of data attribute ?

Comment: The problem is I can't edit the script anymore because I can't get to the edit button. The edit button of the script is on the page that the script runs on and the script immediately redirects me from that page to a page with a blank screen. So now first I need to find a way to be able to edit my script again, then I can try and find a solution to the blank page.

Comment: is the javascript placed in a webpart ?

Comment: Yes, a "Script Editor".

Comment: lets say your page is http://example.com/sites/default.aspx add the query string ?contents=1 to the page it will take you to the manage web parts page you can remove the script editor web part from there

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you so much! I don't use stackoverflow a lot so I'm not sure how to reward you but if you place it as an answer I can select it as the correct answer. Again thanks a lot! Now I don't have to delete the page or something.

Comment: Added some explanation for you in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the webpart maintenance page which allows you to remove and manage web parts without visiting the page, the instructions are as below.

Lets say your page is example.com/sites/default.aspx add the query string ?contents=1 to the page it will take you to the manage web parts page you can remove the script editor web part from there.

The other way is to use SharePoint designer to remove the web part this will also help you achieve the same result.